# Received an invalid response. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access

Tags: javascript

I am following a book example hence the code is very simple.
This is the code:
I see an error in Chrome console:

```
$(function() {
    $(".lang").change(function(){

    var element = $(this);

    var id = element.attr("value");

    if(id == 'english')
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "jsfiles/english.js",
            dataType: "script"
        }); 
    }

    return false;

    });

});
```

Comment: Are you running this on your own computer, by any chance? As opposed to uploading it to a server?

Answer (score 14):

Origin `null` means you are loading the HTML document directly from your file system. You can't use XMLHttpRequest without HTTP.

Either install a web server for your development, or dynamically generate a `<script src="..."></script>` instead.